# Placing button between groupview and childview in android listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm using *ExpandableList* and I want to place a button(or Image) over the list and between the group and child view when expanded.

I'm also using
*BaseExpandableListAdapter*
in my adapter

my code goes like this

```
 @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lesson_list, parent, false);
        mGroupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        mGroupViewHolder.indicatorIV = (IndicatorView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mGroupViewHolder.titleTV = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mGroupViewHolder.subtitleTV = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        mGroupViewHolder.homeworkRateView = (CircleProgressView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homework_rate);
        mGroupViewHolder.header = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        mGroupViewHolder.headerTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_tv);

        convertView.setTag(mGroupViewHolder);
    } else {
        mGroupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (isExpanded) {
        mGroupViewHolder.indicatorIV.setState(IndicatorView.STATE_ON);
    } else {
        mGroupViewHolder.indicatorIV.setState(IndicatorView.STATE_OFF);
    }

    Lesson lesson = mGroupList.get(groupPosition);
    LessonDatum lessonDatum = lesson.lessonData.get(0);

    mGroupViewHolder.homeworkRateView.setProgress(lessonDatum.homeworkRate / 100.0f);
    mGroupViewHolder.homeworkRateView.setText(lessonDatum.homeworkRate + "%");                     
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Context context = parent.getContext();
    Lesson lesson = mGroupList.get(groupPosition);
    LessonDatum lessonDatum = lesson.lessonData.get(0);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_lesson_list, null);
        mChildViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
        mChildViewHolder.chapterLV = (ExpandedListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chapterListView);
        mChildViewHolder.homeworkLV = (ExpandedListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeworkListView);
        mChildViewHolder.homeworkProgressTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.homework_progress_tv);
        mChildViewHolder.homeworkProgressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.homework_progress_bar);
        convertView.setTag(mChildViewHolder);
    } else {
        mChildViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    int homeworkRate = lessonDatum.homeworkRate;
    mChildViewHolder.homeworkProgressTV.setText(homeworkRate+"%");
    mChildViewHolder.homeworkProgressBar.setProgress(homeworkRate);

    final ArrayList<String> chapterList = new ArrayList<>(lessonDatum.chapters.size());
    for (Chapter c : lessonDatum.chapters) chapterList.add(c.content);
    ArrayAdapter<String> chapterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chapterList);
    mChildViewHolder.chapterLV.setAdapter(chapterAdapter);

    final ArrayList<String> homeworkList = new ArrayList<>(lessonDatum.homeworks.size());
    for (Homework h : lessonDatum.homeworks) homeworkList.add(h.content);
    ArrayAdapter<String> homeworkAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, homeworkList);
    mChildViewHolder.homeworkLV.setAdapter(homeworkAdapter);



    final ClipboardManager clipboardManager =  (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    mChildViewHolder.homeworkLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CharSequence charSequence = homeworkList.get(position);
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("LABEL",charSequence);
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);

        }
    });
    mChildViewHolder.chapterLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CharSequence charSequence = chapterList.get(position);
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("LABEL", charSequence);
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

You can easily imagine the view when thinking of "floating action button" in android L I guess.

pls help!

Comment: I tried placing buttons using margin like "-20dp" on my xml but, it didn't seemed to work. Image was croped by margin of each view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in this way

Adding *android:clipChildren="false"* in my xml worked like a charm
which I placed at the top margin like this

```
    <ImageView
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material"/>
```

What I had to do additionally was also to put *android:clipChildren="false"* in parentviews.

self solved.
So sad that I can't post pictures to help understanding due to no reputation.